# Create a "flag" column in a dataset based on a another table in R

Tags: r

I have two datasets: `dataset1` and `dataset2`.

```
zz <- "id_customer id_order order_date
1 1 2018-10
1 2 2018-11
2 3 2019-05
3 4 2019-06"

dataset1 <- read.table(text=zz, header=TRUE)

yy <- "id_customer order_date
1 2018-10
3 2019-06"

dataset2 <- read.table(text=yy, header=TRUE)
```

`dataset2` is the result of a query where I have two columns: `id_customer` and `date` (format YYYY-mm).
Those correspond to customers which have a different status than the others in the source dataset (`dataset1`), for a specified month.

`dataset1` is a list of transactions where I have `id_customer`, `id_order` and `date` (format YYYY-mm as well).
I want to enrich `dataset1` with a "flag" column for each line set to 1 if the customer id appears in `dataset2`, during the corresponding month.

I have tried something as follows:

```
dataset$flag <- ifelse(dataset1$id_customer %in% dataset2$id_customer &
                         dataset1$date == dataset2$date,
                       "1", "0")
```

But I get a warning message that says 'longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length'.
I understand that but cannot come up with a solution. Could someone please help?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! As it stands, your question is hard to answer, since we don't have your data. Please create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/4303162) and add it to your question such that we can reproduce the problem and test possible solutions.

Comment: But I guess that `dataset1` and `dateset2` don't have the same number of rows.

Comment: look up the `merge` function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a flag to dataset2 then use `merge()`, keeping all rows from dataset1.  Borrowing Chris' data:

```
dataset2$flag <- 1
merge(dataset1, dataset2, all.x = TRUE)

   ID    Date flag
1   1 2018-12   NA
2   1 2019-11   NA
3   2 2018-13   NA
4   2 2019-10   NA
5   2 2019-11    1
6   2 2019-12   NA
7   2 2019-12   NA
8   3 2018-12    1
9   3 2018-12    1
10  4 2018-13    1
```

Answer (score 1):

It is very is to add a corresponding flag in a `data.table` way:

```
# Load library
library(data.table)

# Convert created tables to data.table object
setDT(dataset1)
setDT(dataset2)

# Add {0, 1} to dataset1 if the row can be found in dataset2
dataset1[, flag := 0][dataset2, flag := 1, on = .(id_customer, order_date)]
```

The result looks as follows:

```
> dataset1
   id_customer id_order order_date flag
1:           1        1    2018-10    1
2:           1        2    2018-11    0
3:           2        3    2019-05    0
4:           3        4    2019-06    1
```

A bit more manipulations would be needed if you would have the full date/time in the datasets.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**:
This seems to work:

**Illustrative data**:

```
set.seed(100)
dt1 <- data.frame(
  ID = sample(1:4, 10, replace = T),
  Date = paste0(sample(2018:2019, 10, replace = T),"-", sample(10:13, 10, replace = T))
)
dt1
   ID    Date
1   2 2019-12
2   2 2019-12
3   3 2018-12
4   1 2018-12
5   2 2019-11
6   2 2019-10
7   4 2018-13
8   2 2018-13
9   3 2018-12
10  1 2019-11

dt2 <- data.frame(
  ID = sample(1:4, 5, replace = T),
  Date = paste0(sample(2018:2019, 5, replace = T),"-", sample(10:13, 5, replace = T))
)
dt2
  ID    Date
1  2 2019-11
2  4 2018-13
3  2 2019-13
4  4 2019-13
5  3 2018-12
```

**SOLUTION**:

The solution uses `ifelse` to define a condition upon which to set the 'flag' `1`(as specified in the OP). That condition implies a match between `dt1`and `dt2`; thus we're using `match`. A complicating factor is that the condition requires a *double* match between two columns in each dataframe. Therefore, we use `apply` to paste the rows in the two columns together using `paste0` and search for matches in these compound strings:

```
dt1$flag <- ifelse(match(apply(dt1[,1:2], 1, paste0, collapse = " "), 
                         apply(dt2[,1:2], 1, paste0, collapse = " ")), 1, "NA")
```

**RESULT**:

```
dt1
   ID    Date flag
1   2 2019-12   NA
2   2 2019-12   NA
3   3 2018-12    1
4   1 2018-12   NA
5   2 2019-11    1
6   2 2019-10   NA
7   4 2018-13    1
8   2 2018-13   NA
9   3 2018-12    1
10  1 2019-11   NA
```

To check the results we can compare them with the results obtained from `merge`:

```
flagged_only <- merge(dt1, dt2)

flagged_only
  ID    Date
1  2 2019-11
2  3 2018-12
3  3 2018-12
4  4 2018-13
```

The dataframe `flagged_only`contains exactly the same four rows as the ones flagged `1` in `dt1`-- voilà!

Comment: This seems to work and solve the fact that my two datasets don't have the same number of rows. Cheers!

Comment: Just after checking because I had weird outcomes, I realized that there is a problem: some rows are marked whereas they should not. It flags rows where IDs are actually in dataset2, but the dates are not

Comment: On my end it does work, even on larger datasets. You can also try reduplicating the `Date`value where the two dataframes match on the two conditions: `dataset1$flag2 <- dataset1$Date[match(dataset1$ID,dataset2$ID) & 
                          match(dataset1$Date, dataset2$Date)]`--this flags exactly the same rows.

Comment: If you can provide a somewhat larger sample of your data I could perhaps help more efficiently. Also, have you made sure you have adapted your code correctly so that it matches mine?

Comment: I really cannot figure out what goes wrong and continue to get the same issue... I could send you the two datasets so that you could see the problem by yourself maybe.. I sadly do not have enough reputation points to start a chat

Comment: Yeah, why not. I think it is not customary to share email addresses on SO but you can easily google me via my name plus Freiburg University. I have time tomorrow so I could have a peek at your data.

Comment: Really glad it does! Took me some time to figure it out... Please do feel free to accept the answer!